# Invalid Access Token Format is reported during status update

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, social-networking

I've integrated **Twitter4j** to status update from the Android Application.

I am able to view Login page of Twitter & submit login info.

But before status update i use following code for getting access token.

```
Share.mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(
                accessToken, accessTokenSecret));
```

it's throwing an error before `updateStatus(msg)`:-

```
Invalid access token format.
```

Comment: do you resetting access token?